# docker on WSL was not able to start

Tags: bash, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing docker on WSL windowns 10 it was not able to start giving me error as

unaikku@SFCAWL-9123C6F:/etc/docker$ sudo service docker status

- Docker is not running

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had install Docker desktop and to turn on WSL 2 based engine and then go to PS and do wsl --list and ensure you see docker wsl started and then type wsl in PS. The default distro will have docker daemon running. You can get into that wsl by typing code . and that will start visual studio for your default distro and you should be able to do

docker ps

[image]

[image]